# converting array into json object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a problem while converting an array into Json object. I have an array which contain json objects/objects, when i convert that array into Json object it combine/concatenate array data rahter than making json array. 
lets suppose array have two json objects. when i convert it into json object using

```
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(array);
var jsn = JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

here is my code:

```
var array = new Array();

function addBatch(){
var data = $.toJSON($('#risk').serializeArray());
    //data = [{"name":"user","value":"INCRE"},{"name":"period","value":"100"},{"name":"hori","value":"12"},{"name":"conf","value":"32"}] 


    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    var json=JSON.parse(jsonData);
    console.log('After Converting Json');

    //store data in array 
    array.push(json);
}

// function that convert array into json:
function saveBatch(){
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(array);
        json = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        console.log("Batch: "+json);

}
```

it give me following output:

```
[{"name":"user","value":"HIST"},{"name":"period","value":"12"},{"name":"hori","value":"32"},{"name":"conf","value":"12"}],[{"name":"user1","value":"INCRE"},{"name":"period","value":"12"},{"name":"hori","value":"32"},{"name":"conf","value":"12"}]
```

it should be like this:

```
[
  [
      {"name":"obj1"},{"value":"data"}
  ],
  [
      {"name":"obj2"},{"value":"data2"}
  ]
```

]

dont know why this is happening. I search on Google as well but i didn't find any way except

```
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(array);
    var jsn = JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

Comment: "json object" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: It should not be possible for `JSON.stringify` to give the output you say it is outputting. Please provide a complete test case (which includes the original data).

Comment: Could you please show us your input JSON and how you do the output (which is unexpected)? Seems to work.

Comment: `{"value","data2"}` is invalid. It should be `{"value":"data2"}`. Is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: What are you outputting this to? Are you outputting `jsondata`? Your output is not valid JSON or JavaScript. You need to show us what `array` is.

Comment: Please take the time to learn [what is JSON](http://www.json.org/) as you seem confused. The first few lines will do.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? JSON.parse and stringify applied together don't do anything useful to the data usually (OK, they copy a whole structure, and they filter out functions, null values etc).

Comment: @Aesthete the extra comma is a typo. The structure provided otherwise is valid json.

Comment: @limelights - I was referring to the "output" of `[{"name":"obj1"},{"value":"data"}],[{"name":"obj2"},{"value","data2"}]` being two arrays seperated by a comma, not the comma in the last map.

Comment: @Aesthete running that same structure through jslint says its valid. Its the code format in his post that missed a ].

Comment: After edits … why on earth do you want an array of single-member arrays?

Comment: @JamesAllardice yeah it is {"value":"data2"}, Sorry it just a type mistake that i commit above

Answer (score 0):

What you have doesn't make alot of sense. Are you sure you don't want an array of objects?

```
var array = new Array();

function addBatch() {
  // Gets data. Returns an array of objects in format [{name: "", value: ""}, ...]
  var data = $.toJSON($('#risk').serializeArray());

  // Extend the `array` with new objects.
  array.concat(data);
}

// function that convert array into json:
function saveBatch() {
    // Convert the array of objects to JSON string.
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(array);
    console.log(jsonData);
}
```